# Add multiple suffix in Amazon Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

When configuring trigger from Amazon S3 to Amazon Lambda, how can we add multiple suffix? Currently it seems Lambda only supports a single suffix.

Comment: You can create multiple events, each of which has a different suffix. But you can't create one Event with multiple suffixes. An alternative is to create an Event for any suffix (any file type) and have the Lambda function examine the filename and exit if it has an uninteresting suffix.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine filters using a logical AND, however a filter can have at most **one prefix** and **zero or more tags**.

Did you try creating **two** configurations pointing to the same cloud function as so:

```
  <CloudFunctionConfiguration>
     <Id>1</Id>
     <Filter>
            <S3Key>
                <FilterRule>
                    <Name>suffix</Name>
                    <Value>.jpg</Value>
                </FilterRule>
            </S3Key>
     </Filter>
     <CloudFunction>arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:444455556666:cloud-function-A</CloudFunction>
     <Event>s3:ObjectCreated:Put</Event>
  </CloudFunctionConfiguration>
  <CloudFunctionConfiguration>
     <Id>2</Id>
     <Filter>
            <S3Key>
                <FilterRule>
                    <Name>suffix</Name>
                    <Value>.png</Value>
                </FilterRule>
            </S3Key>
     </Filter>
     <CloudFunction>arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:444455556666:cloud-function-A</CloudFunction>
     <Event>s3:ObjectCreated:Put</Event>
  </CloudFunctionConfiguration>
```

Comment: I configured Lambda from UI. Where can I find this configuration file?

Comment: Nath, it's the same UI where you write code for lambda function, the tab - configuration.

Comment: Hey @rock3t, in the configuration section there is no such option to manually add config. Atleast I am not able to find. Can you please attach a screenshot, tutorial to guide me how to do it?

Comment: Hey @K.Nath, I use CloudFormation, so can't really do a screenshot. I went to check deployed Lambda functions and you are right, can't find where to edit config... that being said, here's the [HowTo of S3 event notifications](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html), you might find your answer there.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be possible inside a single trigger (̶w̶h̶a̶t̶ ̶a̶ ̶p̶i̶t̶y̶)̶, but still it isn't that expensive to create multiple S3 triggers for Your lambda function each with it's own suffix, most likely one of a couple of file extensions Your lamda must react to, right?